# Powershell array with single hashtable

Tags: powershell

I am trying to build a Powershell array containing a single hashtable.

```
$params = @{
        "name" = "bob"
        "age" = "30"
        }


$params | ConvertTo-Json
```

current output:

```
{
"age":  "30",
"name":  "bob"
}
```

Desired output:

```
 [
    {
    "age":  "30",
    "name":  "bob"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
$params = @{
        "name" = "bob"
        "age" = "30"
        }


 ConvertTo-Json @($params)
```

The `@()` syntax makes it an array.

You have to give the `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet the input as a parameter, because the pipeline will automatically "unroll" the array and you'll be right back where you started.

Comment: thats it! I did keep ending up back right where I started! Thanks!